# Same-origin conditions in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc, aws-api-gateway

So I have configured spring boot application and configure CORS filter

```
@Bean
public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
    config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
    config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
    config.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
    config.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    return new CorsFilter(source);
}
```

To interact with back end I have configured Amazon Api Gateway and I have configured custom domain name for Api Gateway https:// api.mydomain.com. Site use https:// api.mydomain.com to interact with my back end. Site and back-end(Api) located on the same server. test.mydomain.com (site) and test.mydomain.com:7000 (api)

When I have sent request from the site to back-end through ApiGateway I didn't receive the required answer for CORS to check headers :
Access-Control-Allow-Origin
Access-Control-Allow-Methods
Access-Control-Allow-Headers
I have received response without this header. During investigation and debugging I have found that in org.springframework.web.cors.DefaultCorsProcessor my request defined as same-origin request.

```
org.springframework.web.util.WebUtils

    /**
         * Check if the request is a same-origin one, based on {@code Origin}, {@code Host},
         * {@code Forwarded} and {@code X-Forwarded-Host} headers.
         * @return {@code true} if the request is a same-origin one, {@code false} in case
         * of cross-origin request.
         * @since 4.2
         */
        public static boolean isSameOrigin(HttpRequest request) {
            String origin = request.getHeaders().getOrigin();
            if (origin == null) {
                return true;
            }
            UriComponentsBuilder urlBuilder;
            if (request instanceof ServletServerHttpRequest) {
                // Build more efficiently if we can: we only need scheme, host, port for origin comparison
                HttpServletRequest servletRequest = ((ServletServerHttpRequest) request).getServletRequest();
                urlBuilder = new UriComponentsBuilder().
                        scheme(servletRequest.getScheme()).
                        host(servletRequest.getServerName()).
                        port(servletRequest.getServerPort()).
                        adaptFromForwardedHeaders(request.getHeaders());
            }
            else {
                urlBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpRequest(request);
            }
            UriComponents actualUrl = urlBuilder.build();
            UriComponents originUrl = UriComponentsBuilder.fromOriginHeader(origin).build();
            return (actualUrl.getHost().equals(originUrl.getHost()) && getPort(actualUrl) == getPort(originUrl));
        }
```

This condition skips adding CORS header to the response.
Headers from request:

```
Origin=https://test.mydomain.com
Host=test.mydomain.com:7000
X-Forwarded-Port=443 (this header added by Api Gateway)
X-Forwarded-Proto=https (this header added by Api Gateway)
```

Method isSameOrigin compare actualUrl and originUrl. To meat condition this Url`s should be totally same (protocol, host and port). OriginUrl is url based on Origin header https:// test.mydomain.com. ActualUrl is url based on Host header with applied values from "Forwarded" headers  test.mydomain.com:7000 → (apply X-Forwarded-Port)  test.mydomain.com:443 → (apply x-forwarded-proto) https:// test.mydomain.com:443. Because of this OriginUrl https:// test.mydomain.com:443 (443 is port for https) are equals to ActualUrl https:// test.mydomain.com:443.

As I understand Host header is header which contains path to the endpoint. X-Forwarded-Proto/X-Forwarded-Port request headers help to identify the protocol(HTTP or HTTPS) and port  that a client used to connect to the proxy. But why isSameOrigin method adapts X-Forwarded-Proto/X-Forwarded-Port to the host value is not clear because the provenance of these Forwarded and Host headers are different.

Could you please clarify why Spring filter identifies my request as Same-Origin in particular why it uses method adaptFromForwardedHeaders(request.getHeaders()). I  have tried to find reasons in commits but there are no explanations  https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/9a52c8144313a5093bf6b7153cd89857aaed1899#diff-82a2156da5855b577acb70b86fade1ca .

It could be that Amazon ApiGateway misses/ignores header X-Forwarded-Host to identify the host, which client use to connect to the proxy.

BTW: when I use my endpoint directly (without using proxy Api Gateway) all works fine and my endpoint returns Access-Control-Allow headers.

Answer (score 0):

You're right that API Gateway will not use X-Forwarded-Host to identify the host.